# Numbering of subsections in the appendix

Tags: sectioning, numbering, appendices

I am trying to write an appendix where:

- The appendix is considered as a section, and has the title "appendice"
- Subsections are numbered with letters (it does it for sections by default)

However, I can't get the appendix to be called anything, neither have I succeded in modifying the default numbering.

Comment: Well, if I understand correctly what you would like, this is pretty much the default behavior in the `article` class, isn't it? Which document class are you using?

Comment: @Corentin yes I'm using `article` as a documentclass. The default seems to be that sections, not subsections, are numbered with letters. Subsections are numbered A1, A2... where A is the section. If I omit the section (which I would want to be the appendix itself) all I get is subsections numbered .1,  .2,  ...

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry I read your post too fast. So what would be the numbering scheme that you would like? A.a, A.b,...?

Comment: @Corentin no not really, I'm really only interested in numbering in subsections, since that's pretty much the only section level I want to use (\section being the level of the appendix itself). I would like to keep using the \appendix environment though, since I want theorems numbered with letters. The reason for all this is that sections would be too bulky in relation to their length, and to the length of sections in the main body of my thesis.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Would anything like this example match your needs?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}   
\lipsum[1]

\appendix
\section*{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}

\subsection{Appendix Subsection}
\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Another appendix Subsection}
\lipsum[3]  
\end{document}
```

Here's how it looks like:
[image]

If I understood correctly, you do not want to use any other `\section` than for the headings "Appendix" in itself, so a solution is to use `\section*` at this place and modify the command that issues subsection numbers by deleting the section number (otherwise you would get .A, .B,...) and printing the subsection counter in capital alphabetic form: this is what the

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}
```

line does.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! Great strategy using `\section{Appendix}`, hadn't thought of it. Theorem numbering works fine as well. Upvoted and accepted :)