# Headings in appendix `\section*`

Tags: header-footer, appendices

I'm using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97373/36389) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30123/36389) approaches to get my appendix sections as I want, so a MWE of my code would look like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{abc}
def
\section{ghi}
jkl

\appendix
\clearpage
\section*{Ap: ETC}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{{Ap: ETC}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{A.\arabic{subsection}}
App. content.

\subsection{First A.}
F. A. content.
\subsection{Second A.}
S. A. content.

\end{document}
```

The problem is that this makes the appendices pages heading to be the previous non-appendix section's one. One option may be to use `\pagestyle{myheadings}` and `\markboth` but, is there any more automatic solution?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91468/510

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have only one section in the appendix, it's better to define a command that does everything needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{headings}

\newcommand{\appsection}[1]{%
  \clearpage
  \appendix
  \section*{#1}%
  \markboth{#1}{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
  \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{A.\arabic{subsection}}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\section{abc}
def

\section{ghi}
jkl

\appsection{Ap: ETC}

App. content.

\subsection{First A.}
F. A. content.
\subsection{Second A.}
S. A. content.

\end{document}
```

[image: contents]

[image: appendix page]

This might be easily changed if there's more than one section in the appendix. Say

```
\newcommand{\startappendix}{%
  \clearpage\appendix
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}%
}

\newcommand{\appsection}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \section*{#1}%
  \markboth{#1}{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
}
```

so that you can say

```
\startappendix

\appsection{First}
...

\appsection{Second}
...
```

Comment: For a `\section*` in the `article` class, shouldn't one use `\markboth` (to ensure correct headings with the `twoside` option)?

Comment: @lockstep The example doesn't say `twoside`, but in that case `\markboth{#1}{}` should be used.

Comment: I'd have thought that `\markboth{#1}{#1}` would yield correct results for both `oneside` and `twoside`. Did I overlook something?

Comment: After checking [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35680/36389) I would suggest, to fake the heading properly, to change `#1` with `\MakeUppercase{#1}`. Or even with 2 arguments: `#1` for "Ap: " and `\MakeUppercase{#2}` for "Etc", if it is "Etc" and not "ETC".

Comment: @Andrestand This is assuming you *like* all uppercase headers. ;-) I don't. But, if you need they are that way, of course add `\MakeUppercase`.